# AngularJS testing nested directives

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, nested

I am trying to test an AngularJS directive that includes other directives.On using karma and Jasmine to test it I get multiple errors. Here's some example code:
I have directive called Project Plan. It has 2 other directives ivh-dropdown and dateRange

...

```
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-12 form-inline">
      <label class="col-sm-5 col-lg-2 ">{{'FORM.APPLICATION' | translate}}
      </label>
      <div class="col-sm-7 col-lg-7">
        <ivh-dropdown style="margin-right:50px;width:44%;"
                      ivh-model="appGrpList"
                      selected-Text="newProperties.application">
        </ivh-dropdown>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-12 form-inline">
                <label class="col-sm-5 col-lg-2 ">
                  {{'FORM.DATE_RANGE' | translate}}
                </label>
                <div class="col-sm-7 col-lg-7">
                    <date-filter
                        on-click-date-filter="onselectDateFilter(dates)"
                        from-date="newProperties.startDate"
                        to-date="newProperties.endDate"> \
                    </date-filter>
                </div>
            </div>
  </div>
```

...
On running this test code I get

```
'use strict'
describe('Project Plan Directive', function() 
{
  var compile, scope, directiveElem;
  beforeEach(module('demoApp'));

  /* should be the path from root
  the path to your templateURL needs to match exactly to the path to the 
templates inside the files section in karma config*/
  beforeEach(module('js/directives/projectPlan/projectPlan.html'));

  beforeEach(inject(function($compile, $rootScope){
    compile = $compile;
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    directiveElem = getCompiledElement();
  }));

  function getCompiledElement()
  {
    var element = angular.element('<esi-project-plan></esi-project-plan>');
    var compiledElement = compile(element)(scope);
    scope.$digest();
    return compiledElement;
  }
  it('Check form validity', function() 
  {
    //scope.$digest();
    var formObject = directiveElem.isolateScope().myform;
    expect(formObject.$invalid).toBeTruthy();
    expect(formObject.Taskname.$invalid).toBeTruthy();
    expect(formObject.label.$invalid).toBeTruthy();
    expect(directiveElem.find('button')[0].disabled).toBeTruthy();
    expect(directiveElem.find('button')[1].disabled).toBeFalsy();
  });
```

...

Error

```
Error: Unexpected request: GET js/directives/ivh-dropdown/ivh-dropDown.html
error properties: Error
    at <Jasmine>
    at $httpBackend (angular-mocks.js:1226)
    at m (angular.min.js:83)
    at f (angular.min.js:80)
    at angular.min.js:112
    at l.$eval (angular.min.js:126)
    at a.$$ChildScope.$$ChildScope.$digest (angular.min.js:123)
    at getCompiledElement (projectPlanSpec.js:34)
    at UserContext.<anonymous> (projectPlanSpec.js:27)
    at Object.e [as invoke] (angular.min.js:37)
    at UserContext.workFn (angular-mocks.js:2350)
    at <Jasmine>
    at window.inject.angular.mock.inject (angular-mocks.js:2321)
    at Suite.<anonymous> (projectPlanSpec.js:24)
    at <Jasmine>
    at projectPlanSpec.js:2
```

I have tried including 
beforeEach(module('js/directives/ivh-dropdown/ivh-dropdown.html'));
beforeEach(module('js/directives/dateRange/dateRange.html'));

but if I do that

```
beforeEach(inject(function($compile, $rootScope){
    compile = $compile;
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    directiveElem = getCompiledElement();
  }));
```

code is not entered!

My Karma config is

```
// Karma configuration
module.exports = function(config) {
    config.set({
      client: {
        jasmine: {
          random: false
        }
      },
      // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, 
exclude)
      basePath: '',
      frameworks: ['jasmine'],
      //the path to your templateURL needs to match exactly to the path to 
the templates inside the files section in karma config
      //if it doesn't match use ngHtml2JsPreprocessor:{stripPrefix:'app/'} 
to strip any starting folders to make it the same as the unit test file
      // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
      files: [
        'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
        'node_modules/angular/angular.min.js',
        'node_modules/angular-ui-bootstrap/dist/ui-bootstrap.js',
        'node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
        'node_modules/lodash/index.js',
        'node_modules/backbone/backbone.js',
        'node_modules/graphlib/dist/graphlib.core.js',
        'node_modules/dagre/dist/dagre.core.js',
        'node_modules/ng-file-upload/dist/ng-file-upload-shim.min.js',
        'node_modules/ng-file-upload/dist/ng-file-upload.min.js',
        'node_modules/angular-translate/dist/angular-translate.js',
        'node_modules/angular-ui-grid/ui-grid.min.js',
        'js/thirdparty/build/rappid.js',
        /*'js/config/*.js',*/
        'js/app.js',
        'js/constants.js',
        'js/config/*.js',
        'js/services/*.js',
        'js/tab.js',
        'js/i18n.js',
        'js/directives/**/*.js',
        'js/directives/**/*.html' 
      ],
      // list of files / patterns to exclude
      exclude: [
        '**/*.swp',
        '**/*.bak',
        '**/*.js~',
        'js/directives/content-layout/**/*.js'
      ],
      preprocessors: {
        'js/directives/**/*.html':['ng-html2js']
      },
      reporters: ['spec','dots','junit','coverage','html','jasmine-runner'],
      junitReporter: {
        outputFile: 'test-results.xml'
      },
      htmlReporter: {
         outputFile: 'tests/units.html',
        // Optional
        pageTitle: 'Unit Tests',
        subPageTitle: 'A sample project description',
        groupSuites: true,
        useCompactStyle: true,
        useLegacyStyle: true
      },
      // web server port
      port: 9876,
      // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
      colors: true,
      // level of logging
      // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || 
config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
      logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


      // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any 
file changes
      autoWatch: true,


      // start these browsers
      // available browser launchers: 
https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
      browsers: ['Chrome'],
      plugins : [ 
        'karma-chrome-launcher',
        'karma-jasmine',
        'karma-spec-reporter',
        'karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor',
        'karma-junit-reporter',
        'karma-html-reporter',
        'karma-coverage',
        'karma-htmlfile-reporter',
            'karma-jasmine-runner-reporter'
      ],

      // Continuous Integration mode
      // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
      singleRun: false,

      // Concurrency level
      // how many browser should be started simultaneous
      concurrency: Infinity
    })
  }
```

My package.json is

```
{
  "name": "",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "js/main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",
    "start-live-server": "node node_modules/live-server/live-server.js --    
port=9876 --cors",
    "test": "karma start karma.config.js",
    "install-deps": "npm install --dev",
    "build-win": "node_modules/.bin/electron-builder.cmd -w",
    "test-jasmine": "http-server -c-1 -o js/directives/SpecRunner.html -p 
1337 -w *.js/*.html",
    "webpack-prod": "webpack --config webpack-production.config.js -p",
    "watch": "webpack-dev-server --port 3000"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "electron": "~1.8.2",
    "electron-builder": "^19.35.1",
    "http-server": "^0.11.1",
    "jasmine": "^3.1.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^3.1.0",
    "jasmine-jquery": "^2.1.1",
    "jasmine-runner": "^0.2.9",
    "jsdoc": "^3.5.5",
    "jshint": "^2.9.6",
    "jshint-loader": "^0.8.4",
    "karma": "^2.0.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "^1.1.2",
    "karma-html-reporter": "^0.2.7",
    "karma-htmlfile-reporter": "^0.3.5",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-runner-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "karma-js-coverage": "^0.4.0",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "1.2.0",
    "karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.4",
    "karma-spec-reporter": "0.0.32",
    "node-libs-browser": "^2.1.0",
    "protractor-beautiful-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "strip-loader": "^0.1.2",
    "webpack": "^4.16.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "1.3.7",
    "angular-mocks": "1.3.7",
    "angular-translate": "2.6.0",
    "angular-ui-bootstrap": "^2.5.6",
    "angular-ui-grid": "3.0.6",
    "backbone": "1.3.3",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "bootstrap-datetime-picker": "^2.4.4",
    "dagre": "0.7.4",
    "graphlib": "1.0.7",
    "jquery": "^2.2.4",
    "live-server": "1.1.0",
    "lodash": "3.10.1",
    "ng-file-upload": "^12.2.13",
    "protractor": "5.3.2",
    "rgbcolor": "^1.0.1",
    "stackblur": "1.0.0",
    "watch": "^1.0.2",
    "daterange": "~1.0.0",
    "angular-markdown-editor": "1.1.0"
  }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to install karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor, then configure it in your karma.config like so:

```
plugins: [
  ...etc,
  'karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor',
  ...etc
],
preprocessors: {
  ...etc,
  'app/**/*.html': ['ng-html2js'],
  ...etc
},
```

Then, it shouldn't have an issue loading your html. You don't need to inject it in the beforeEach. Oh, and make sure to give it YOUR route to the html. I used 'app/**/*.html' as an example.

You then need to add this to the top of your spec file:

```
beforeEach(module('HtmlTemplates'));
```

'HtmlTemplates' is the name of the module, not a substitute for a path to a file or anything. Don't change the name of the module.

Comment: I already had the same setup in my karma config. 
    preprocessors: {
            'js/directives/**/*.html':['ng-html2js']
          },
 plugins : [ 
        'karma-chrome-launcher',
        'karma-jasmine',
        'karma-spec-reporter',
        'karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor',
        'karma-junit-reporter',
        'karma-html-reporter',
        'karma-coverage',
        'karma-htmlfile-reporter',
 'karma-jasmine-runner-reporter'
      ],
any other possibility for error?

Comment: I updated, looks like you're also missing the html module.

Comment: I already had  beforeEach(module('js/directives/projectPlan/projectPlan.html')); as part of projectPlanSpec.js

Comment: adding   beforeEach(module('js/directives/projectPlan/projectPlan.html'));
  beforeEach(module('js/directives/ivh-dropdown/ivh-dropdown.html'));
  beforeEach(module('js/directives/dateRange/dateRange.html')); doesn't help
beforeEach(inject(function($compile, $rootScope){...} is not entered

Comment: You don't need any of that. You just need the HtmlTemplates. I'm not using a substitute, you literally need to include 'HtmlTemplates'.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that. I tried it but looks like I am having the same symptoms beforeEach(inject(function($compile, $rootScope){...} is not entered

Comment: What is your whole error? I also usually see test files and inject arguments formatted like this:

beforeEach(inject(function(\_$compile\_, \_$rootScope\_)...

Comment: Error: [$injector:modulerr] this is the error I get. The URL is too big to paste in the comments box. But the URL leads to a 'page not found' page so no clues there.

Comment: Did you try the syntax I just posted, adding underscores before and after your arguments? Also, post your whole karma config. You could have something wrong, like path to files or basePath property. Posting your Package.json wouldn't hurt, either.

Comment: Yes, I tried beforeEach(inject(function(_$compile_, _$rootScope_){ ... } same symptoms. I have updated my question to include karma.config.js